# Convert String To Int in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, casting

I have a LINQ query that queries a DataTable.  In the DataTable, the field is a string and I need to compare that to an integer, basically:

```
if ((electrical >= 100 && electrical <= 135) || electrical == 19)
{
    // The device passes
}
```

the problem is, I am trying to do this in LINQ like this:

```
        var eGoodCountQuery = 
            from row in singulationOne.Table.AsEnumerable()
            where (Int32.Parse(row.Field<String>("electrical")) >= 100 &&
                   Int32.Parse(row.Field<String>("electrical")) <= 135) &&
                   Int32.Parse(row.Field<String>("electrical")) != 19 &&
                   row.Field<String>("print") == printName
            select row;
```

I keep getting the exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format

The main problem occurs when electrical == ""

Comment: Doesn't it work if you do `row.Field<int>` instead of `row.Field<String>` for the `electrical` field?

Comment: what about .KeyAsString in the row field?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, that would not work.

Comment: What is the actual value of the field. If it really is a numerical string than your code should work. If even only one of the rows contains a non-numerical value it will fail. Are there rows which have a non-numerical value?

Comment: Well, what's actually in the "electrical" field?  What's the actual type of the object, and what's it's contents?  Perhaps it can't be parsed to an int, or perhaps it's not a string to begin with?  Use the debugger to see what it looks like when it fails.

Comment: SqlFunctions.StringConvert(whatever_var)

Comment: @kformeck, validate your expectations of the table. From the error message, it is clear that the "electrical" field contains *at least one* record with a non-integer string. If these records are valid, what do you want to do with them, in regards to your query?

Comment: @AnnArbor87, that is not applicable here. This is linq-to-objects, SqlFunctions is not supported in this context.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, that gives a "Specified cast is invalid" error.

Comment: @user414076, The type of the electrical column is a String.  There is always a value for this column, so it will never be a "" or null.  Also, there is always an integer value held in it, but instead of being 105 for example, it is "105".  I need to essentially be able to compare "105" to 105.

Comment: The error proves at least one of those assumptions false. "Input string is not in a correct format." Either the string is empty, or the string contains a non-integer value. There's no two ways about it. *Visually* inspect your datatable in your debugger. What's in it? (Note also that "105.0" would be just as invalid as "apple".)

Comment: Is there a reason that the column "electrical" is a string instead of an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get anything to work, so I re-did the whole method:

```
    public bool GetElectricalStatus(string printName)
    {
        List<object> eGoodList = new List<object>();
        var eGoodCountQuery =
            from row in singulationOne.Table.AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<String>("print") == printName
            select row.Field<String>("electrical");

        foreach (var eCode in eGoodCountQuery)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eCode.ToString()))
            {
                int? eCodeInt = Convert.ToInt32(eCode);
                if (eCodeInt != null &&
                    (eCodeInt >= 100 && eCodeInt <= 135) || eCodeInt == 19)
                {
                    eGoodList.Add(eCode);
                }
            }
        }
        if (eGoodList.Count() > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The main problem occurs when electrical == ""

Comment: Note that if you *updated your question* with the useful tidbit about the empty string, people could make your original query work.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the framework doesn't provide a nice clean way to handle parsing scenarios where it fails.  Of what's provided, they only throw exceptions or use `out` parameters, both of which does not work well with linq queries.  If any one value you're parsing fails, the entire query fails and you just can't really use `out` parameters.  You need to provide a method to handle the parsing without that does not throw and does not require using `out` parameters.

You can handle this in many ways.  Implement it where upon failure, you return some default sentinel value.

```
public static int ParseInt32(string str, int defaultValue = 0)
{
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(str, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

Or what I would recommend, return a nullable value (`null` indicating it failed).

```
public static int? ParseInt32(string str)
{
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(str, out result) ? result : null;
}
```

This simplifies your query dramatically while still leaving it readable.

```
public bool GetElectricalStatus(string printName)
{
    var query =
        from row in singulationOne.Table.AsEnumerable()
        where row.Field<string>("print") == printName
        // using the nullable implementation
        let electrical = ParseInt32(row.Field<string>("electrical"))
        where electrical != null
        where electrical == 19 || electrical >= 100 && electrical <= 135
        select row;
    return !query.Any();
}
```

p.s., your use of the `Convert.ToInt32()` method is incorrect. It is the same as calling `Int32.Parse()` and *does not* return a nullable, it will throw on failure.

Answer (score 4):

I would check if the data in the column does not contain leading/trailing whitespaces - i.e. `"15   "` rather than `"15"` and if it does (or might do) trim it before trying to convert:

`Int32.Parse(row.Field<String>("electrical").Trim())`

BTW:  not related to the error but I'd use `let` statement to introduce a local variable and do the conversion once:

```
let x = Int32.Parse(row.Field<String>("electrical").Trim()) 
where x >= 100...
```

Comment: this does not fix the problem

Comment: This does not work and throws: Not Implemented
 Inner exception message:
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: it would work if you finalized the dataset before doing it.  That would switch it to linq to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a function that does your evaluation, and call it in your Linq query. Put logic in to check the validity of the data contained within (so if you can't parse the data, it should return **false**)...

The function:

```
bool IsInRange(string text, int lower, int upper, params int[] diqualifiers)
{
  int value = int.MinValue;
  if (!int.TryParse(text, out value)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!(value >= lower && value <= upper)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (disqualifiers != null && disqualifiers.Any(d => d == value)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The Linq query...

```
var eGoodCountQuery = 
            from row in singulationOne.Table.AsEnumerable()
            where 
              IsInRange(row.Field<String>("electrical"), 100, 135, 19) 
              && row.Field<String>("print") == printName
            select row;
```